# MP3 player for OS X with wide timer bar

Tags: macos, software-rec, mp3, media-player

I am trying to play back sound files on my Macintosh, recordings of lectures made with a digital recorder.  The problem is that in iTunes, the timer bar is very narrow, so if I want to "rewind" by a few seconds I can't do it: a milimeter on the timer bar represents about a minute, so obviously there is no way to rewind by a few seconds.

That means it takes about 4 hours to listen to a 90 minute lecture, because every time I back up to hear a sentence that I missed I waste an entire minute, or more.

Garage Band won't recognize my mp3 files, and I tried Audiofile Engineering Wave Recorder, and it won't read my MP3 files either.

I need a program that will play MP3 sound files on a Macintosh and that has a very wide timer bar so that I can rewind by very small increments of time.  None of the product reviews seem to address this issue.  Can anyone recommend a product?

Comment: In iTunes, you can scrub back 5 seconds at a time with Command + Option + [←].

Answer (score 7):

Try [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/). It can get rather wide.

[image: VLC media player can get rather wide.]

Comment: `Ctrl ←` to rewind per minute and `Shift ←` to rewind 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think VLC will play the audio file and I think it has a wide timer bar, haven't used it in awhile so I don't know for sure.